# Is this proof of $a\leq b_1$ for every $b_1>b$, then $a\leq b$ logically correct?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

Let $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$. Show if $a\leq b_1$ for every $b_1>b$, then $a\leq b$. Solve using proof-by-contradiction and write out using logical premises.

**Proof:** Let $Q: a\leq b_1$ for every $b_1>b$ and $R:a\leq b$ then $P:Q\to R$. Suppose $\neg P$, then we have $\neg P\iff Q\land\neg R$. Thus suppose $a>b$ and let $b_1=\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and consider $Q$. We have $b_1>b$ but $a>b_1$ hence $\neg R\to\neg Q$. Hence we have
$$(\neg P\Rightarrow Q\land\neg R) \land(\neg P \Rightarrow\neg R\to\neg Q)\iff\neg P\Rightarrow F$$
and thus $P$ must be true. $\square$

I am uncertain about the last step where I have $\neg P \Rightarrow\neg R\to\neg Q$ and use it to combine the contradiction $(Q\land\neg R)\land(\neg R\to\neg Q)$.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand what you're doing if you _don't_ abbreviate your meaningful propositions as $P$, $Q$, $R$.

Comment: Also: It's almost always a confusing detour to attempt to prove an implication by contradiction. If you want to prove $Q\to R$, assume $Q$ and seek to derive $R$. _Now_ you may choose to prove $R$ by contradiction if you must -- but there's no need to justify the initial assumption of $Q$ as proof-by-contradiction. Assuming $Q$ is simply how you prove an implication _directly_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah, sorry for that. I do it  because I am practicing writing logical expressions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm My goal is to negate $P$ and show that $\neg P\to F$ to prove $P$. I don't understand what you mean by proving $R$.

Comment: x @Bright: And I'm saying that's a roundabout, confusing plan.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Shouldn't the contradiction be $\neg P \Rightarrow Q \land \neg Q$? Since I've assumed $\neg R$ and have $\neg R \to \neg Q$ I could just plug it in...

Comment: What I'm saying is that you shouldn't attempt to prove your $P$ by contradiction _at all_ -- at least if you want a proof that looks halfway natural to a human reader.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's just an exercise I have to do. I don't really have a choice here.

Comment: x @Bright: That is not stated anywhere in your question. Please edit the question to contain the _full_ statement of the exercise you're solving.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's because I didn't expect anyone to advise me to not attempt this.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The exercise is to write out the proof-by-contradiction using logic. I have done that. The question is about the result of my attempt and not about the exercise as a whole.

Comment: With this wording I still think it is much more likely that what is meant is "Assume $\forall b_1(b_1>b\to a\le b_1)$ and then prove $a\le b$ by contradiction", rather than "prove $\forall b_1(b_1>b\to a\le b_1) \to a\le b$ by contradiction".

Comment: @HenningMakholm So, I should assume such-and-such and show that assuming a>b leads to a contradiction with such-and-such?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would interpret it to mean. The meat of it is still the same computation you're already doing (basically, if $a>b$ then there is a $b_1$ strictly between $b$ and $a$), but rounding off the proof afterwards will be much simpler.

Comment: I think that I can just round it off by saying that since $\neg P$ is assumed to be true we have that $Q\land\neg R$ must be true. Since $\neg R\to \neg Q$ is true $\neg Q$ must be true as well. Hence, we have that $\neg R \land Q\to\neg Q \land Q$ and hence $\neg P\to Q\land\neg Q$. Thus $P$ is true

Comment: If you insist of writing your proof in that horribly confusing and convoluted way, suit yourself.